# Node.Js Express Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, basic-authentication, passport.js

I have a simple self-made API in my Node.Js / Express app. It requires authentication. My problem is that I don't want the user to have to authenticate via browser (basic authetication) if they already logged into the app using the normal means (I use `passport` local strategy). Currently, however, it's not the case, so I wanted to ask you to help me to write it right...

In app.js I have the following strings:

```
var api2 = require('./routes/api2');
app.use('/api2', api2.auth);
```

In routes/api2.js I have:

```
exports.auth = express.basicAuth(User.authenticate);
```

Then when the actual request happens, processed via

```
app.get('/api2/user/statements/:context?', api2.entries);
```

The user is first requested their user/password – basic authentication - via a standard browser dialog (even if they logged into the app via passport) and only then `exports.entries` is initiated in api2.js file.

I want that the user is requested their user/password via the browser dialog only if they haven't logged in the app via passport.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are [Basic/Digest authentication strategies](http://passportjs.org/guide/basic-digest/) for Passport as well, you could do something like:

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(...));
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(...));

// set up your Express middlewares
// ...
app.use(passport.initialize());
// if you use passport.session(), you must have included the Express session
// middleware somewhere up above
app.use(passport.session());
// ...

// then use passport.authenticate wherever you need to protect some route(s)
// this will try the local strategy first, then basic
app.use('/api2',
        passport.authenticate(['local', 'basic']));
```

Comment: Thank you! Would I use passport.use instead of app.use then in this case? Or how could it be implemented into the structure above?

Comment: I've updated the example. It should point you in the right direction.